# Emails corrupt and a winmail.dat file attachment added for only one mail box

Tags: dovecot, procmail

I have one mailbox that's receiving emails from a particular company who use Outlook and all emails sent to that one address are stripped of their proper structure and a winmail.dat file is attached.

This is only happening for single mail box on my server. The rest of our staff on the same server receive messages unmodified and intact from the same senders.

We are using Ubuntu 14.04, Virtualmin, Procmail, Postfix and Dovecot combination.

I've tried creating a new mail box on a new server and copied all emails across via an IMAP sync script to the new account but the emails still come through stripped only for that account, others are fine.

I managed to look at samples of the emails sent to our server and compared the source code.

One difference was that after the Received: and before the From: the following line is inserted in the bad email:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="_000_2A63131FAB54A14B88827878643A8A4221489EEBKELLYEX01domain_"
```

Another difference is the email that looks fine has no X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:

```
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
```

And the broken email has:

```
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <2A63131FAB54A14B88827878643A8A4221489EEB@XXXX-EX-01.DOMAIN.local>
```

I've checked /var/log/procmail.log and there's nothing in there that indicates extra filtering. Are there individual settings for a mail box that could be causing this?

Comment: Procmail by itself does nothing of the sort, but if the mailbox has a `.procmailrc`, that could do pretty much anything, possibly without leaving any trace in the log.

Comment: Thanks tripleee .. There's no .procmailrc file for this user so I will need to find another method to troubleshoot this.

Comment: If the user's client is doing something to the messages after they arrive, the ones delivered to Procmail should still be fine.  Adding a simple `.procmailrc` to save a copy of every incoming message to a temporary location (`:0c` (newline) `/tmp/safety` where obviously the destination has to exist and be writable) might help narrow the scope of the problem, at least.

Answer (score 0):

"This is only happening for single mail box on my server." - are You sure? Maybe for this single account another mail client software is being used? What mail client is being used for this account?

If it's Thunderbird, then You could try the "LookOut" add-on
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/lookout/

IMO this has nothing to do with the server/procmail, that's a mail-client related problem.

Comment: Hi Thomas .. thanks for your answer.. Yeah I'm using Thunderbird. And I have that addon installed as a workaround but the emails are still a mess.  I've also tried switching mail clients and it still happening.